# Are there disadvantages of having a higher designation at low salary?

Tags: promotion, salaried-pay

I have a situation at hand. I have a option to get a higher Designation (Senior Software Engineer) but the remuneration being provided is less then whats average in the market for a SSE.

My question is if i take the designation at low salary will it effect my future growth as i will be low paid SSE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two aspects this will have impact on:

- future salary prospects within your current company
- perceived value to other potential employers

## Salary prospects

Usually there is some pool of extra salary companies hand out year-by-year in the form of small-ish percentage increases. **New titles are always opportunities to negotiate pay raises** beyond what these annual increases would give you, so to **situate yourself better for future raises**, you should drive a hard bargain to come with a new title (as there is new responsibility involved, too). On the other hand *you don't want to be passed over* when promotions are coming up. So there's a **trade-off when chosing this route**.

## Outside value

If your short to medium term *plan is to leave/switch companies* anyway, grabbing **titles and certifications will put you in a better position** when negotiating with potential new employers.

This may differ from country to country but **I don't know of any laws that force you to disclose your exact current/last salary** during an interview, so accepting a lower-than-average one for a **promotion that will increase standing** may be a good idea.

## Conclusion

You have to know *which direction your 'future growth' is taking*, then the **answer will be clear**.

Answer (score 2):

Not really, many companies promote from within because it allows them to increase your salary rather than provide you with a new one, which sometimes leads to you being paid a little less than someone employed from outside.  Which never really made sense to me because you have specific domain knowledge and can hit the ground running.

As well as that, some companies have less resources so can't pay more.

Anyway, companies tend to understand this and it won't make a difference to most.

Comment: Often times the excuse goes like "we can't give you a 12% pay raise when all your colleagues only get 2%, just because you were lucky to score a new title". Is it even mandatory to disclose your current salary to other companies during interviews?

Answer (score 0):

No, the salary may be lower than average but your still be getting senior position experience.  You can then easily request a payrise at your next appraisal or transfer to a better paying company in the future.